# App Sharing is giving nil data

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, share-extension

I am creating an iPhone app and iWatch app. I want to share data from iPhone app to iWatch app.
I am using app group for both and saving data in User Defaults using suit name. But when I am retrieving values in iWatch then it is always nil.

I have created three provisioning profiles. One for app, second for watch kit and third for watch kit extension. All three having same group name. and from capabilities I have enabled App sharing and it is showing correct group name which I have enabled by clicking on it.

After that, In ViewController.swift (iPhone App)

```
 let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.addSuite(named: "group.group.com.demo.appgroup")
        userDefaults.set("12345", forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled")
        userDefaults.synchr
```

onize()

and in InterfaceController.swift (In Watch Extension)

```
let storageKey = "group.group.com.demo.appgroup"
        let userStorage = UserDefaults(suiteName: storageKey)

        // Get setting from storage or default
        if userStorage?.object(forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled") == nil
        {
            print("Data is nil")
        }
        else
        {
            lblTest.setText(userStorage?.object(forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled") as? String)
        }
```

But while I am fetching data fin watch extension, it is always giving me nil.

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Would you care to post some code to help us duplicate the issue?

Comment: Post your sample code here...

Comment: Please check the sample code

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a shared app group?

The Apple documentation goes into quite specific detail about how to set this up. Also, it's a somewhat well-documented issue that people have trouble getting user defaults to work in the simulators, while they do work fine on real devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Settings.html

**I know that talks about a settings bundle, but it works the same way for value exchange. It's important to note that Apple really would prefer you to use WCSession to transfer data between devices.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

1.Enable AppGroups in Watch Extension and Main App in capabilities

2.Try Code:

```
let AppGroup = "group.com.demo.appgroup"
let AppUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: AppGroup)
AppUserDefaults.set("12345", forKey: "isDarkModeEnabled")
AppUserDefaults?.synchronize()
```

Comment: Synchronize: "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."